# Get error value of LinearLayout Height? The value is doubled. Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, height, android-linearlayout

I try to get LinearLayout Height on Activity, but I get the height value is doubled. PS:height is 60 but I get 120.

Someone can help? 
Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_head1"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
package com.example;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
    import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class GdomRefreshableActivity extends Activity {
        private LinearLayout l1;
        TextView t1;
        @Override
        //create
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gdom_refreshable);

            l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_head1);
            t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);          
                 ViewTreeObserver vto2 = l1.getViewTreeObserver();  
                    vto2.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override  
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            l1.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);  
                            int h = l1.getHeight();
                             int ht = t1.getHeight();
                            Log.d("GdomRefreshableActivity2",String.valueOf(h));
                        }  
                    });
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Layout:
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_head1"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>

Comment: Could you move the XML to the question body? It is easier to read. Thnx